# How to pass value in recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am developing an app in which I'm using `RecyclerView` and `CardView`. In that when I am clicking on an item I want that item value to be passed to another `Activity`. I want if i click on 1st item,it should pass the value of 1st item and when i click on 2nd item it should pass the value of 2nd item.But It is  passing only 1st item value if i am clicking on any item

Here is my code for `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                getData();
                upcomingJobs.clear();
                upcomingJobs.addAll(upcomingJobs);
                // fire the event
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    });

    // Make call to AsyncTask
    getData();
    return v;
}

private void getData() {
    final boolean checkConnection=new Application_utility().checkConnection(getActivity());

    if(!checkConnection) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
                getContext()).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Connection");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please Check Your Internet Connection");

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
               getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

    } else {
        class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                 progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                 progressDialog.dismiss();

                parseJSON(s);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(Config.GET_URL);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetData gd = new GetData();
        gd.execute();
    }
}

public void showData() {
    adapter = new CardAdapter(Config.offer, Config.offprice, Config.bitmaps, Config.price, Config.urls);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void parseJSON(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        config = new Config(array.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Config.offer[i] = getoffer(j);
            Config.urls[i] = geturl(j);
            Config.offprice[i] = getoffprice(j);
            Config.price[i] = getprice(j);
            Config.urls[i] = geturl(j);
            final int finalI = i;
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent a=new Intent(view.getContext(),Details.class);
                    a.putExtra("Config.offer", Config.offer[finalI]);
                    startActivity(a);
                }
            }));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GetBitmap gb = new GetBitmap(getContext(), this, Config.urls);
    gb.execute();
}

private String getoffer(JSONObject j) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = j.getString(Config.TAG_Offer);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

private String getoffprice(JSONObject j) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = j.getString(Config.TAG_offprice);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

private String getprice(JSONObject j) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = j.getString(Config.TAG_price);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

private String geturl(JSONObject j) {
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = j.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
 }
 }
```

And here is code for `DetailActivity`:

```
public class Details extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String Name = intent.getStringExtra("Config.offer");
        t1.setText(Name);
    }
}
```

And here is my code for adapter class:

```
 public class CardAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MyDataHolder> {
public List<ListItem> upcomingJobs;
public  class MyDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public View view;

    public TextView offer, offprice, price, url;
    public MyDataHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        offer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer);
        offprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Offerprice);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        url = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        price.setPaintFlags(price.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    }
}
public CardAdapter(String[] offer, String[] offprice, Bitmap[] image, String[] price, String[] url) {
    super();
    upcomingJobs = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < offer.length; i++) {
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.setoffer(offer[i]);
        item.seturl(url[i]);
        item.setoffprice(offprice[i]);
        item.setprice(price[i]);
        item.setimage(image[i]);

        upcomingJobs.add(item);

    }
}


@Override
public MyDataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, parent, false);

    return new MyDataHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyDataHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListItem uj = upcomingJobs.get(position);
    holder.offer.setText(uj.getoffer());
    holder.offprice.setText(uj.getoffprice());
    holder.price.setText(uj.getprice());
    holder.url.setText(uj.geturl());
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(uj.getimage());

}

 @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
    return upcomingJobs.size();
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the adapter on your recyclerview?

Comment: simple because you are passing only one value in `Intent`. so in the end you are receive only one value.

Comment: Here i am setting the adapter:   public void showData() {
        adapter = new CardAdapter(Config.offer, Config.offprice, Config.bitmaps, Config.price, Config.urls);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); @Bhargav

Comment: So how to pass like if i click on 1st item it will pass 1st value..like this?? @Ironman

Comment: Show your CardAdapter class's code, don't put it as a comment here but edit your question and add the code in there at the end

Comment: @user see Reaz Murshed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put other information in the `Intent` which is being passed to the `DetailsActivity`.

So your `OnItemClickListener` should look like this.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent a = new Intent(view.getContext(),Details.class);
        a.putExtra("Config.offer", Config.offer[finalI]);
        a.putExtra("Config.urls", Config.urls[finalI]);
        a.putExtra("Config.offprice", Config.offprice[finalI]);
        a.putExtra("Config.price", Config.price[finalI]);
        startActivity(a);
    }
}));
```

And from `DetailsActivity` just extract all the values from the intent you've received.

```
public class Details extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String Offer = intent.getStringExtra("Config.offer");
        String Urls = intent.getStringExtra("Config.urls");
        String OffPrice = intent.getStringExtra("Config.offprice");
        String Price = intent.getStringExtra("Config.price");

        // Now set your textviews here.
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Update**

So if I have understood your problem correctly, you have to take the `OnItemClickListener` outside of your `for` loop and set the listener like this. And another thing is, you need to use `position` as the index of `Config.offer`like this: `a.putExtra("Config.offer", Config.offer[position]);`

So here's the updated code for you

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
    Config.offer[i] = getoffer(j);
    Config.urls[i] = geturl(j);
    Config.offprice[i] = getoffprice(j);
    Config.price[i] = getprice(j);
    Config.urls[i] = geturl(j);
}

// Move the click listener outside 
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent a=new Intent(view.getContext(),Details.class);
        a.putExtra("Config.offer", Config.offer[position]);
        startActivity(a);
    }
}));
```

Comment: No. You just passed one value to the `Details.class`. I sent all the values you got there.

Comment: NO i dnt want like that..i want if i click on 1st item,it should pass the value of 1st item and when i click on 2nd item it should pass the value of 2nd item.It is is passing only 1st item value if i am clicking on any item